# Copy Pasting and Apostrophes in MySQL Command Line

Tags: mysql

I'm using the MySQL Command Lind Tool on MacOS using the command: `mysql -u root -p;`

To avoid repetition and to save time, I tried using TextEdit (MacOS's Notepad counterpart) to type queries and then copy them into the MySQL command prompt.

Here I noticed a problem when I was copy-pasting syntactically correct queries.
e.g. `select * from club where COACHNAME=‘coolname’;`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that the problem was with the apostrophes.
In any text editor, the apostrophes are tilted in different directions: `‘See the left and right tilted apostrophes on both sides’`

But the same doesn't take place in the terminal, or in MySQL (not sure whose default it is).
Wherein the same apostrophes are used for both the start and the end: `'Notice the un-tilted and uniform apostrophes on both sides'`

Hence when I was copy pasting: `select * from club where COACHNAME=‘coolname’;`
I was meant to change the titled-apostrophes to the uniform kind that are built-in, i.e.
 `select * from club where COACHNAME='coolname';`

You can even notice that the apostrophes on Stack Overflow by default are the uniform kind,
whereas those in TextEdit and Notes (and maybe also in Notepad, if somebody could confirm that) are the tilted kind.

Comment: Yes - I have to turn off "Smart Quotes" in any editor I use for coding. A programming editor will do this by default. On some operating systems, you can turn off Smart Quotes for all apps, by using system preferences.

Comment: I have also had to turn off Smart Quotes and other automatic text replacement features in some chat applications where I share code with other people. Skype for example (though no one I know uses Skype these days).